# How to specify a logback configuration as a classpath resource rather than a file

Tags: logback

I have the following situation.  I need to be able to run two programs launched by different batch files where each batch file invokes a java class with main() from the same jar.  I would like each program to have its own log.  However, the second program is an installer for the first, and therefore, I don't want to/can't easily specify -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config file as that location may not yet exist.

[Logback documentation seems to provide a solution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty) but I need an example of how to make it work:

> Specifying the location of the default configuration file as a system
>   property
>
> If you wish, you can specify the location of the default configuration
>   file with a system property named logback.configurationFile. The value
>   of this property can be a URL, a resource on the class path or a path
>   to a file external to the application.
>
> java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml
>   chapters.configuration.MyApp1

Can anyone point me to an example where logback.configurationFile is defined as a resource on the classpath as opposed to the file system?

Comment: If it's just the log-file that you wish to change why not define the log-file as a variable in a single logback.xml configuration file.  This is particularly good if most of the logging configuration is the same. Then the logfile name can be read from a resource in the classpath or be part of the installer's invocation.

Answer (score 17):

You can simply put a `my-logback.xml` in the root of one of your classpath entries and specify `-Dlogback.configurationFile=my-logback.xml`. Internally it will probably use `ClassLoader#getResource(String name)` to get the file - check the JavaDoc of this method for more information.

Comment: that will work, I suppose, but out of curiosity, how would you do it for a place beneath the root on the classpath?

Comment: I actually tried it now and it does work. Can you check your setup again?

Comment: You must omit the leading / for it to pull from the classpath. If logback.xml is in the /etc directory in your jar, logback.configurationFile = etc/logback.xml

Answer (score 4):

the answer to this question is in the supplied link:
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty
with the examples below:

The contents to include can be referenced as a file, as a resource, or as a URL.

```
As a file:
To include a file use the file attribute. You can use relative paths but note that the current directory is defined by the application and is not necessarily related to the path of the configuration file.

As a resource:
To include a resource, i.e a file found on the class path, use the resource attribute.

<include resource="includedConfig.xml"/>

As a URL:
To include the contents of a URL use the url attribute.

<include url="http://some.host.com/includedConfig.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a *slightly* different solution than offering command line arguments.

My project is set up like so:

```
| foo
  - src
    - conf
      - logback.xml
    - main
    - test
```

I wanted the `logback.xml` outside of the jar since I had the `scanPeriod` set for live reload. I figured since it should get picked up on the classpath, I'll add the path to the `manifest.mf` and it'll get picked up automatically.

---

Related parts of `foo`'s `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<plugins>
  . . . Some plugins before
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/conf</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
          <mainClass>com.company.foo.main.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
          <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
        </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  . . . Some plugins after
</plugins>
```

#### Important things to take note of:

- Maven Resources Plugin

  - Copies all files in `src/conf` to the standard compilation folder `target/conf`.
- Maven Jar Plugin

  - Adds the `conf` folder to the `MANIFEST.MF`'s classpath so that you don't need to specify the location on the command line.
  - **All files** in the `conf` folder will be added to the classpath, not just `logback.xml`

---

For the jar to run in this scenario, the `conf` folder **must** be placed alongside the jar. It will look like so:

```
path/to/jar
  | foo.jar
  | lib/
  | conf/
    | logback.xml
```

---

The `MANIFEST.MF` looks something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: $user
Class-Path: lib/x.jar lib/y.jar lib/z.jar conf/
version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.2
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_161
Main-Class: com.company.foo.main.Main
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I went ahead and tried it out.

If the logback config file is local to the jar (in the same jar you're running in), this works:

```
System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", "org/package/path/your.logback.xml");
```

works.  If it's in the classpath 'anywhere'.  Which is really weird since normally with a call to `getResource` you have to specify it with a preceding slash like:

`YourClass.class.getResource("/org/package/path/your.logback.xml")` so not sure why.

Other more exotic resource paths like specifying the exact jar also seem to not work.  Weird.